# Decision Tree AttributeError: module 'sklearn.tree' has no attribute 'plot_tree' Error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

I want to show decision tree figure for my data visualization. But there is an errror appeared in the console.

```
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.tree' has no attribute 'plot_tree'
```

Although I install extra modules via `!pip install -U scikit-learn` and `!pip install --upgrade sklearn`, the error cannot be solved.

How can I fix the issue?

Here is my code shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree

data = pd.read_csv("files/data.csv")
data.drop(["id","Unnamed: 32"],axis=1,inplace=True)
data.diagnosis = [1 if each == "M" else 0 for each in data.diagnosis]

y = data["diagnosis"].values
x_data = data.drop(["diagnosis"],axis=1)

x = (x_data - np.min(x_data))/(np.max(x_data)-np.min(x_data))

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.3,random_state=1)

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt.fit(x_train,y_train)

print("score: ", dt.score(x_test,y_test))


tree.plot_tree(dt,
              feature_names = data.columns,
              rounded = True,
              filled = True,
               class_names = ["diagnosis"],
              impurity = True)
```

Comment: what version of scikit learn are you running?

Comment: @Mike print(sklearn.__version__) -> 0.20.1

Comment: I believe you need to be running 0.22

Comment: @Mike All right, How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you running an anaconda distribution of python or a standard distribution

Comment: @Mike  I mainly use Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda.

Comment: From your terminal run:

conda install scikit-learn=0.22.1

Comment: @Mike it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213638/discussion-between-mike-and-tony-brand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer.

After updating all packages defined in Anaconda Navigator, the code snippet I wrote works flawlessly.